# Multiple left joins in Linq to Entity to get the desired result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm not very proficient in Sql and Linq.I have five tables

> LookupType
>
> ```
> LookupTypeId LookupTypeName 
> 3            Days
> ```

LookupValue

```
LookupValueId   LookupTypeId   Value
1               3              Monday
2               3              Tuesday
...             ..             ...
...             ...            ...
7               3              Sunday
```

Job

```
JobId
6
```

JobRequest

```
JobRequestId  DayId   JobId
1             2       6
2             4       6
```

DayId comes from the LookupValue table(LookupValueId)

JobRequestShift

```
JobRequestShiftId   JobRequestId  Time
1                   1             03:10:56
2                   1             05:10:56
3                   2             03:11:03
4                   2             04:26:14
5                   2             05:10:56
```

Job has one to many relationship with JobRequest and JobRequest has one to many relationship with JobRequestShift.
I want data in the format

```
DayName    JobRequestId  JobRequestShifts(List of JobRequestShifts)
```

---

```
Monday     null          null

Tuesday    1             JobRequestShiftId   JobRequestId  Time
                         1                   1             03:10:56
                         2                   1             05:10:56
Wednesday null           null

Thursday  2              JobRequestShiftId   JobRequestId  Time   
                         3                   2             03:11:03
                         4                   2             04:26:14
                         5                   2             05:10:56
Friday   null            null
Saturday null            null
Sunday   null            null

In an attempt to get the desired result I have come up with this


from lt in LookupTypes
join lv in LookupValues
on lt.LookupTypeId equals lv.LookupTypeId
join jr in JobRequest.Where(rcr => rcr.JobId == jobId)
//join jr in JobRequest.Include(jr => jr.JobRequestShifts).Where(rcr   =>    rcr.JobId == jobId)
//got an exception
on lv.LookupValueId equals jr.DayId into SelectedDays
from sd in SelectedDays.DefaultIfEmpty()
join jrs in JobRequestShifts
on sd.JobRequestId equals jrs.JobRequestId into JobShifts
from rs in JobShifts.DefaultIfEmpty()
where lt.LookupTypeName == "Days" 
select new
{
   lv,
   sd,
   Shifts = JobShifts
}
```

After that I intend to project the result on my Entity class.

Comment: What's the issue? The query looks ok (just remove `from rs in JobShifts.DefaultIfEmpty()` line)

Comment: Thanks Ivan. rs in JobShifts.DefaultIfEmpty() was redundant.

Comment: Try to replace the joins by *navigation properties*. Much easier. But again, what's the issue? You follow the pattern of many questioners: I want this -- I tried this -- period. You should tell what's wrong with what you tried. (Actually, this puts you high in the league of questioners, many don't even show what they tried).